# Is it possible to use a rgY color space?

Tags: colors, rgb, color-space

Would it be possible to take a rgY color space:

```
r = R / (R + G + B)
g = G / (R + G + B)
Y = R * 0.299 + G * 0.587 + B * 0.114
(unnecessary) b = 1 - r - g
```

and convert it back to RGB? If so, how would it be done?

Comment: Hint: R = r*(R+G+B); G=g*(R+G+B). And now you have a system of three linear equations with 3 unknowns.

Comment: You can solve the three equations for R, G and B, but converting colorspaces is normally a lossy procedure because of value clamping, so you might not get back in what you took out.

Comment: What are you using rgY for, or where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

(No factorials are in this answer. The syntax is similar to Wolfram-Alpha plain text output standards, exception being spaces are placed before and after the != [not equals] sign and the use of 'if [conditional] then' statements.)

- if r = 0 and 473 g+114 != 0 and Y != 0 then

  - R = 0 and G = (1000 g Y)/(473 g+114) and B = -(1000 (g-1) Y)/(473 g+114)
- if Y = 0 and g = 1/473 (-185 r-114) and r != 0 then

  - G = -((185 r+114) R)/(473 r) and B = ((587-288 r) R)/(473 r) and R!=0
- if Y = 0 and r = 0 and g = -114/473 then

  - R = 0 and B = -(587 G)/114 and G!=0
- if 473 g+185 r+114 != 0 and r != 0 and r Y != 0

  - R = (1000 r Y)/(473 g+185 r+114) and G = (1000 g Y)/(473 g+185 r+114) and B = -(1000 Y (g+r-1))/(473 g+185 r+114)